# How to calc y coordinate of the block to put it between 2 other?

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

Suppose, we have a flowchart with 2 branches:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes, positioning}
\begin{document}
\def\len{1cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = \len, auto]
\tikzset{
    line/.style = {draw},
    block/.style = {rectangle, draw, text centered, minimum height=2em},
    question/.style = {shape=chamfered rectangle, chamfered rectangle xsep=2cm, draw},
}
%branch 1
\node [question] (1-1) {1-1};
\node [block, below = of 1-1] (1-2) {1-2};
\path [line] (1-1) -- (1-2);
\node [block, below = of 1-2] (1-3) {1-3};
\path [line] (1-2) -- (1-3);
\node [coordinate, below = of 1-3] (1-4) {};
\path [line] (1-3) -- (1-4);
\node [block, below = of 1-4] (1-5) {1-5};
\path [line] (1-4) -- (1-5);
%branch 1
\node [block, right = of 1-2] (2-1) {2-1};
\path [line] (1-1) -| (2-1);
\path [line] (2-1) |- (1-4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Branch 2 has only 1 block. While branch 1 can have more, then 1 block (I used 2 for simplicity).

How can I set node (2-1.y) coordinate = (1-1.south.y) + ((1-1.south.y) - (1-4.y))?

Note: 1-4 is not visualized on the image.

Comment: You can always use the `let` sintax (see manual) to extract the y coord and then do the maths and compute the right coord for `2-1`. However in this situation I would draw a path between `(1-1)[xshift=\len]` and `(1-5)[xshift=\len]` and place it in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

You could proceed by calculating the coordinates but you can also solve this using paths:

```
\path (1-1) -- node[block,xshift=\len](2-1){2-1} (1-4);
\path [line] (1-1) -| (2-1);
\path [line] (2-1) |- (1-4);
```

Here you trace a path between `(1-1)` and `(1-4)` (the two nodes wrt which you want `(2-1)` to be centred vertically) and in the middle, but shifted on the right, you create the node `(2-1)`.